# Google Calendar API Recurrent Event, EXDate not working

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, google-calendar-recurring-events

I want to create a recurrent event into Google Calendar with one day exclusive. I used Google Calendar APi explorer. 
Below is the Request Data

```
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-02-24T19:00:00+05:00",
    "timeZone": "Asia/Karachi"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-02-24T18:30:00+05:00",
    "timeZone": "Asia/Karachi"
  },
  "description": "PSL live Streaming  ..",
  "summary": "PSL live Streaming  ..",
  "location": "National Stadium Karachi",
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20200229T185959Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU",
    "EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20200225"
  ],
  "reminders": {
    "useDefault": false,
    "overrides": [
      {
        "method": "email",
        "minutes": 15
      },
      {
        "method": "popup",
        "minutes": 15
      }
    ]
  }
```

I got response

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#event",
 "status": "confirmed",
 "summary": "PSL live Streaming  ..",
 "description": "PSL live Streaming  ..",
 "location": "National Stadium Karachi",
 "start": {
  "dateTime": "2020-02-24T18:30:00+05:00",
  "timeZone": "Asia/Karachi"
 },
 "end": {
  "dateTime": "2020-02-24T19:00:00+05:00",
  "timeZone": "Asia/Karachi"
 },
 "recurrence": [
  "EXDATE;VALUE=DATE:20200225",
  "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20200229T185959Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU"
 ],
 "sequence": 0,
 "reminders": {
  "useDefault": false,
  "overrides": [
   {
    "method": "email",
    "minutes": 15
   },
   {
    "method": "popup",
    "minutes": 15
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

This event should not be created on 25th, but when i go to google calendar is see event is also created on 25h.
[image]

Any hint, what's been wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided a **dateTime** in `start` and `end`, and a **date** in `EXDATE`.

Since you provided a **dateTime** for `start` and `end`, you should also provide a **dateTime** in `EXDATE`, and the **time** part should match the one you provided in `start`. Otherwise, the API won't know what event to exclude.

That is to say, the recurrence should be like this:

```
"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20200229T185959Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA,SU",
"EXDATE;TZID=Asia/Karachi:20200225T183000"
```

#### Reference:

- [RFC5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5)